# Derive TypeScript interface from discriminiated union

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Consider the following TypeScript code:

```
type AccountType = "staff" | "user"

type StaffAccountName = "owner" | "CEO" | "accountant"

type UserIdentifier =
  | { accountType: "user"; id: number }
  | { accountType: "staff"; id: StaffAccountName };
```

I would now like to make a dictionary that stores age for each user, in the format
`dict[accountType][id] = "age"`

How can I dynamically type such dictionary? I am thinking something like

```
type Dictionary<K,V> = Partial<Record<K,V>>

type AgeDict<UI extends UserIdentifier> = {
   [UI.accountType]: Dictionary<UI.id, number>
}
```

... which obviosuly doesn't work.

---

I really want to avoid having to re-define the allowed type pairs, like:

```
type AgeDict<UI extends UserIdentifier> = {
   "user": Dictionary<number, number>,
   "staff": Dictionary<StaffAccountName, number>
}
```

since I want to be able to rely on a single source of truth for them.

---

**EDIT:** Jcalz's answer lets technically allows me to create the interface, but [I get an error](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxnA9gVwHbACrmgXigIgGdgBDAMzPygB8DlCIAnfAKBdEigGVSL4k0wAHIkAtrgKIA7qiZVa+AMIBRAPLyCJBCnQl0rdtigBVBowCSAEwjoAlmVtMoOFlDc0oAbyhaB6LJAAXHRm+ADcULaWwajIogBGTgC+ru603r46mNjBRLyUEVHBPORk-Fki4lBJYWwc0AAitnDAtoioJIwgADwA0lAQAB7ANpaEUAAKjIiQjKC9ECAANFAAagB8zpOdrSQANt0AShBIjJZ9KxvrdUYwAOYQTS1bnqluANrG5pGoJmZWNlaDicJHGX3eAHJMoIAhAIQBdeHBJ6tdqdHrgiFRBErWIJJjXFIsAD0ACooPVYA8US83lB6ExghMdrZ9kcTogzt08YlGLi4rz1utau4oMRSkyWWzjqdziU+NpBJUIPz8YwhbUklBScS2EhUMQfMF7o9msBaaLxRRgq9RaKVKpggBWAAMSzpoukskYwQALE73Xb3NDdOg-S66UlA+4GT6vB73ABGYIAZgDCbcACZU27IywifrDQ9gCatgAKKKA+yOOOmJgAuzAvlQSxm43Us0ASmcm1bLXelcbNYAdCHspB4QPrEOmMOovCgA) when I try to access it :

```
const getAge = (identifier: UserIdentifier, dict: AgeDict) => dict[identifier.accountType][identifier.id]
//                                                            ^
// Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number | "owner" | "CEO" | "accountant"' can't be used to index type 'Partial<Record<StaffAccountName, number>> | Partial<Record<number, number>>'.
//   No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'Partial<Record<StaffAccountName, number>> | Partial<Record<number, number>>'.(7053)
```

I also need the solution to be able to infer that the function above is valid.

Comment: You would have run into this problem regardless of whether you generated `AgeDict` manually as in your question here, or dynamically as in my solution below.  Hence, your further problem is out of scope here: it's really a separate issue that you might want to ask about in a new question.

Comment: @jcalz I don't think it's quite the same, since my example in the question makes no link between `UserIdentifier` and `AgeDict`, just happens to use the same keys... Which is not really the case for your answer - even though the link doesn't transfer into the resulting type

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're saying.  How could you "dynamically type" the dictionary in a way that doesn't make a "link" between `UserIdentifier`, the type you're processing, and `AgeDict`, the type you're creating?  Could you elaborate on what the issue is?

Comment: That would be impossible. I was referencing the example below `I really want to avoid having to re-define the allowed type pairs, like:`, which I consider static, without any link to `UserIdentifier` - in contrast to your solution which uses `UserIdentifier` directly to dynamically create the resulting type. Maybe I'm using some of my words wrong, but I hope the idea I was trying to get accross is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a mapped type.  In particular, you can use [mapped type key remapping via `as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) as introduced in TypeScript 4.1, like this:

```
type AgeDict = {
    [UI in UserIdentifier as UI['accountType']]: Dictionary<UI['id'], number>
}
```

It's conceptually the same as what you were doing.  You just missed that it needs to be a mapped type (as opposed to a computed key/ index signature thing) and that to look up a property in a type you need [a lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) which uses bracket notation like `UI['accountType']` instead of dotted notation like `UI.accountType` (which isn't supported because it conflicts with type namespaces).

Let's see that it works how you want:

```
/* type AgeDict = {
    user: Partial<Record<number, number>>;
    staff: Partial<Record<StaffAccountName, number>>;
} */

const a: AgeDict = {
    staff: {
        CEO: 50,
        owner: 45,
        accountant: 40
    },
    user: {
        1: 35,
        2: 30,
    }
}
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxnA9gVwHbACrmgXigIgGdgBDAMzPygB8DlCIAnfAKBdEigGVSL4k0wAHIkAtrgKIA7qiZVa+AMIBRAPLyCJBCnQl0rdtigBVBowCSAEwjoAlmVtMoOFlDc0oAbyhaB6LJAAXHRm+ADcULaWwajIogBGTgC+ru603r46mNjBRLyUEVHBPORk-Fki4lBJYWwc0AAitnDAtoioJIwgADwA0lAQAB7ANpaEUAAKjIiQjKC9ECAANFAAagB8zpOdrSQANt0AShBIjJZ9KxvrdUYwAOYQTS1bnqluANrG5pGoJmZWNlaDicJHGX3eAHJMoIAhAIQBdeHBJ6tdqdHrgiFRBErWIJJjXFIsAD0ACooPVYA8US83lB6ExghMdrZ9kcTogzt08YlGLi4rz1utau4oMRSkyWWzjqdziU+NpBJUIPz8YwhbUklBScS2EhUMQfMF7o9msBaaLxRRgq9RaKVKpggBWAAMSzpoukskYwQALE73Xb3NDdOg-S66UlA+4GT6vB73ABGYIAZgDCbcACZU27IywiUA)

Comment: This indeed lets me create the interfece, but doesn't let me access it afterwards - `const getAge = (identifier: UserIdentifier, dict: AgeDict) => dict[identifier.accountType][identifier.id]` throws an error. Any ideas about that? Link in next comment, as it's too long to fit in this one

Comment: Nevermind, still can't post the link in a comment, edited answer instead

Comment: btw, I'd probably solve the followup question with aggressive use of generics and lookup types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/9Wvl3N); it's kind of a tough one because TS doesn't really support [correlated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) so it's either that or an assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/4WyPZm).

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have been immensely helpful. I now understand from [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581#issuecomment-476417974) that it is impossible to find a neat way of typing the record in a way that "just works" and allows me to access the leaf properties directly (for example to assign them) - so I  will use one of your suggestions and reconcile with the fact I will have to assert for direct access - `(a[identifier.accountType] as Dictionary<any, number>)[identifier.id] = newAge`